# How to combine data from Observables data fetched inside a loop made on another Observable result in Angular 7 and RsJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a method that returns an Observable with a car data:

```
getCars(): Observable<any> {
    return this.get(`/cars`);
}
```

And another that returns Obserable with car parts:

```
getCarParts(carName: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.get(`carParts?name=${carName}`);
}
```

getCars returns in data an JSON array of carNames (pseudocode):

```
{
   carName: "Scoda"
},
{
   carName: "BMV"
}
```

car details return various car detail names for a particular carName (pseudocode). For Scoda:

```
{
   carDetail: "SCO1"
},
{
   carDetail: "SCO2"
}
```

For BMW:

```
{
   carDetail: "BMW1"
},
{
   carDetail: "BMW2"
}
```

I would like to fetch all cars with getCars, and for each car fetch car details and combine these car details into one array. The result should look this way (pseudocode):

```
{
   carDetail: "SCO1"
},
{
   carDetail: "SCO2"
}    
{
   carDetail: "BMW1"
},
{
   carDetail: "BMW2"
}
```

If i had just synchronously fetched arrays (not Obserables) it would look something like this (pseudo-lame-code):

```
var cars = getCars();
var carDetails = new Array();
foreach (car in cars)
{
   var details = getDetails(car.carName);
   foreach(detail in details) carDetails.push(details);
}
```

So i would like to combine data from Obserables fetched based on data from another Obserable into one array. How to acomplish this using Angular and RxJS the most proper way?

Comment: Start by defining interfaces and using them in your method definitions, instead of using `any`. It will be much easier to understand what each method actually returns.

Comment: Can you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458269/6663016). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @KiraAG thanks, It seems like i would need to dig deeper into it to know if this is good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my take on your issue :

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tclans)

```js
  cars = of([
    { name: 'Scoda' },
    { name: 'BMW' }
  ]);

  partsScoda = of([
    { part: 'SCO1' },
    { part: 'SCO2' }
  ]);

  partsBMW = of([
    { part: 'BMW1' },
    { part: 'BMW2' }
  ]);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cars.pipe(
      switchMap(cars => forkJoin(
        cars.map(car => this['parts' + car.name]))
      )
    ).pipe(
      map(res => Array.prototype.concat.apply([], res))
    ).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

Start by requesting your list of cars, then map that array to an array of requests. Once each request has been made, it will return an array of arrays : simply flatten this array to obtain your end result.